# SharePoint SQL Server has crashed

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, disaster-recovery

Our SharePoint SQL Server has crashed and Infra team installed new OS and SQL services.

Will SharePoint be back after restore the previous configuration db and content databases or do we need to rebuild the complete FARM from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

If the SQL server name will be same and all the databases restored on the same date & time then it should not be an issue.

- Shut down the share-point servers, my personal experience it is better
- Simply rebuild the SQL server
- Restore the database or attach the Storage drive (if using external
  storage)
- Start the SharePoint servers.
- Test the application.

a good article to read, [SharePoint 2010 Disaster Recovery, Part 2](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-disaster-recovery-part-2)

Comment: yup, once configuration and content databases are up and running again you should be able to reconnect your sharepoint server. also be sure that they are running under the same port